# Freeing memory after calling strtok() causes an error

Tags: c, malloc, strtok

Could you please help me? My code does tokenizing, so I created code like this:

1. I allocate some memory,
2. I `strcpy(malloced_memory, argv)`
3. I execute `strtok(mallocted_memory, ".")`
4. Try `free(mallocted_memory)`.

   ```
   filename = malloc(strlen(argv));

   strcpy(filename, argv);
   strk_ptr = malloc(sizeof(filename));
   strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");//
   i++;
   sprintf(in->file_name,"%s",strk_ptr);

   while(strk_ptr = strtok(NULL,"."))//
   {
       i++;
       sprintf(in->file_name,"%s.%s",in->file_name,strk_ptr);
       sprintf(in->file_ext ,"%s",strk_ptr);
   }
   free(strk_ptr);
   free(filename);
   ```

That code has the problem that I can't `free(filename)`. If I try `free(filename)`, then program get `SIGTRAP`. But program is working.

I want fix that problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
filename = malloc(sizeof(argv));
```

should be this:

```
filename = malloc(strlen(argv) + 1);     /* +1 for the '\0' at the end */
if (filename == NULL) { /* take some action */ }
```

And this line:

```
strk_ptr = malloc(sizeof(filename));
```

is only creating a memory leak since it is followed by:

```
strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");
```

And you should check the return value:

```
strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");
if (strk_ptr == NULL) { /* take some action */ }
```

BTW, the `strtok()` function returns a pointer to a token inside the string passed in the initial call to it (`filename` in your example).   It does not allocate memory, so its return value should NOT be freed (which your program avoids, but it's a common mistake).  While I'm grousing about `strtok()`, I'll mention that you can't (directly or indirectly) pass it a literal string to tokenize, since it modifies the string and literal strings are readonly.  That is, doing: `strtok("sample.txt", ".")` is a no-go.

And finally, this kind of implicit condition is not great form:

```
while (strk_ptr = strtok(NULL,".")) { ... }
```

Better is:

```
while ((strk_ptr = strtok(NULL,".")) != NULL) { ... }
```

Comment: they aren't asking about freeing strtok memory, they are asking about freeing their memory after using strtok.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Thanks, reworded a bit

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to allocate memory when using strtok()**

There is no problem in freeing **filename** as it is correctly allocated by **malloc()**, however there are many other problems and memory leaks. 
Basically you first allocate memory for **str_ptr**:

```
strk_ptr = malloc(sizeof(filename));
```

Here **malloc()** return a pointer which is stored in **strk_ptr**.
And then you call **strtok()** which also return a pointer, inside **filename**:

```
strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");
```

So you lost the original pointer returned by **malloc()** and now **strk_ptr** points somewhere in **filename**. When you call `free(str_ptr)` you are freeing a memory inside **filename**. The subsequent call to `free(filename)` report the error. The solution is simply that don't need to allocate memory for **strk_ptr**.

I wrote a working minimal code to show you how to correctly use **strtok**. Please remember that, when asking a question, posting a minimal working code is alway better.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *strk_ptr;
    char *filename = malloc(strlen(argv[0]) + 1);

    strcpy(filename, argv[0]);

    printf("filename = %s, size = %zu\n", filename, sizeof(filename));

    // Do not malloc this
    //strk_ptr = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
    strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");//
    printf("%s\n", strk_ptr);

    while( (strk_ptr = strtok(NULL,".")) )
    {
        printf("%s\n", strk_ptr);
    }
    free(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

First of all **argv** is a char** so if you want to copy the content of the first argument passed as input you have to use **argv[0]**, which is always the executable file name.

then, `sizeof(filename)` returns the size of the pointer not the size of the content as **filename** is not an array. you have to use `strlen(filename) + 1`.

**strtok** return a pointer inside the object (**filename**) which is already allocated so you *don't need* to allocate memory for **strk_ptr**.

When using strtok in a loop consider to take the following approach:

```
   for (strk_ptr = strtok(filename, "."); strk_ptr; strk_ptr = strtok(NULL, "."))
    {
        printf("%s\n", strk_ptr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 filename = malloc(strlen(argv));
 strk_ptr = malloc(sizeof(filename));
```

strk_ptr gets some memory, which you then go leave dangling by pointing strk_ptr to filenames memory, you then end up double freeing filename.

So don't malloc strk_ptr.  Just leave it as char* then only free filename at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
strk_ptr = malloc(sizeof(filename));
strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");//
...
free(strk_ptr);
```

Doesn't work. At first, `strk_ptr` points to the malloc'd memory but then the pointer is immediately overwritten with some other value, so basically you lose the pointer to the malloc'd memory and hence cannot `free` that memory any more.

Edit:

Seeing `malloc(sizeof(filename))`, I should add that you *do not* have to allocate memory for the pointer variable itself. The declaration `char* strk_ptr;` makes the compiler implicitly allocate memory for that pointer (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes). So you can just use the pointer directly like any other variable, and you won't have to `free` that variable's memory.

```
char* strk_ptr;
strk_ptr = strtok(filename,".");
```

Or, if that wasn't your intention then note that `sizeof(filename)` does *not* return the length of the string, but just the size of the pointer variable `filename`, i.e. usually 4 or 8, independent of what string `filename` points to. See also http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html:

```
char string[32] = "hello, world";
char *ptr = string;
sizeof (string)
    ⇒ 32
sizeof (ptr)
    ⇒ 4  /* (on a machine with 4 byte pointers) */
```